# Jetty 9 JNDI setup - Class not found: org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource

Tags: mysql, jetty, jndi

I'm trying to configure a JNDI entry in Jetty for one of my applications.

I've put the mysql jar: mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar in lib/ext

I've edited start.ini and changed OPTIONS to:
    OPTIONS=Server,websocket,resources,ext,plus

I've also uncommented the lines:

```
OPTIONS=jndi
OPTIONS=plus
etc/jetty-plus.xml
```

When I run: service jetty start I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource in file:/usr/share/jetty-distribution-9.0.4.v20130625/etc/jetty.xml
```

I've checked that the plus jar is in /usr/share/jetty/lib

```
jar tf jetty-plus-9.0.4.v20130625.jar |grep jndi/Resource.class
```

gives:

```
org/eclipse/jetty/plus/jndi/Resource.class
```

So the class is there.

The JNDI entry itself is defined in etc/jetty.xml:

```
...
<New id="fhxprime_test" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
  <Arg><Ref refid="Server"/></Arg>
  <Arg>jdbc/fhxprime_test</Arg>
  <Arg>
    <New class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource">
        <Set name="Url">jdbc:mysql://hostname:3306/dbname</Set>
        <Set name="User">user</Set>
        <Set name="Password">password</Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</New>
</Configure>
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I was modifying the startup.ini on another server